# how to embed font "Courier New" in JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am having trouble in my report, I installed the Courier New font in ireport but by adding to the Report Server JasperReport not appear with the font that was created. I could not install extension font. My environment is windows. help!

Comment: What do you mean by, "I could not install extension font."?

Answer (score 9):

This might be late answer, but since I spent a lot of time to find the solution, I'd like to share it.
To add fonts to the JasperServer so they will be used in PDF export the following steps need to be performed:

1. In **webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\lib** folder find the **jasperreports-fonts-5.0.0.jar** file (I'm using jasper server 5.5.0)
2. Download required TTF fonts (all - regular, **bold**, *italic* and ***bold-italic***)
3. Open the jar (jasperreports-fonts-5.0.0.jar) in archive manager and go to **net\sf\jasperreports\fonts** folder
4. create the folder with the fon't you'd like to add (In my case this is **arial**)
5. put downloaded TTFs into this folder (in my case they are arial.ttf, arialbd.ttf, ariali.ttf and arialbi.ttf)
6. Adjust the fonts.xml in the Jar by adding the following nodes:

> ```
> <fontFamily name="Arial">
>   <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arial.ttf</normal>
>   <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arialbd.ttf</bold>
>   <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ariali.ttf</italic>
>   <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arialbi.ttf</boldItalic>
>   <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
>   <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
>   <exportFonts>
>       <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
>       <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
>   </exportFonts>
> </fontFamily>
> ```

You're done. now you have correct Arial fonts in all exports including PDF.